# Install SonarXML for SonarQube 5.3

Tags: plugins, sonarqube5.3

Need to install SonarXML. In SonarQube 5.3, Update center -> Available, there is SonarXML 1.4.3, and is compatible for SonarQube 5.6+ (Compatible with LTS). How to install SonarXML for SonarQube 5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded and copied sonar-xml-plugin-1.3.jar from [here](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-xml-plugin/) in the installation directory /opt/sonar/extensions/plugins and reboot. Works fine.